# how do I fix my script made in Roblox Lua?

Tags: lua, eof, roblox

I'm making my script and the Script Analysis tool says

> Error: (54,2) Expected , got 'end'

I thought maybe you guys might help.
Here is the code

```
-- to be placed in StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts

local Players = game:GetService("Players")

-- wait for local player PlayerGui
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer
local playerGui = LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")

-- create a ScreenGui
local screenGui = Instance.new("ScreenGui", playerGui)

-- create a holder for our bar
local frame = Instance.new("Frame", screenGui)
frame.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.0, 0.0)
frame.Position = UDim2.new(0.0, 0, 0.0, 0)
frame.Size = UDim2.new(0.0, 0, 0.0, 0)
-- create a bar
local bar = Instance.new("Frame", frame)
bar.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
bar.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
bar.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0, 1, 0)

-- create a sound
local sound = Instance.new("Sound", screenGui)
local lastLoudness = 0
sound.SoundId = "rbxassetid://697821987"
sound.Looped = true
sound:Play()

-- define a max loudness
local maxLoudness = 30

-- animate the amplitude bar
while true do
    local amplitude = math.clamp(sound.PlaybackLoudness / maxLoudness, 0, 1)    
    print(80-(game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView))
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(sound.PlaybackLoudness / maxLoudness, 0, 0, 0)
    wait(0.00001)
        local lastLoudness = 0
            local PBS = ((sound.PlaybackLoudness/50)^(sound.PlaybackLoudness/50))
            if lastLoudness~=0 then
                local formula = math.abs((lastLoudness*15)) + ((lastLoudness+PBS)/1.9)
                if (math.abs(PBS) > formula) == true then
                    game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = (lastLoudness)
                    if game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView <= 10 then
                    print(formula, PBS) 
                    else
                    game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = 0
                    print(formula, PBS)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I genuinely Don't know how to fix the code, So...
Could you guys Help me?
I spent a long time (a couple of hours) on this and I'm legitimately stuck in the deepest pits of coding hell. And I want this fixed SO BADLY.
Also, Just To Clarify, The script is supposed to change FOV when sound.PlaybackLoudness ÷ 50 × sound.PlaybackLoudness ÷ 50 is over 0.

Comment: You have two excessive `end`s at the end of the script

Answer (score 3):

Egor Skriptunoff is right. Let me reformat your while-loop to show you why.

```
-- animate the amplitude bar
while true do
    local amplitude = math.clamp(sound.PlaybackLoudness / maxLoudness, 0, 1)    
    print(80-(game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView))
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(sound.PlaybackLoudness / maxLoudness, 0, 0, 0)
    wait(0.00001)
    local lastLoudness = 0
    local PBS = ((sound.PlaybackLoudness/50)^(sound.PlaybackLoudness/50))

    if lastLoudness~=0 then
        local formula = math.abs((lastLoudness*15)) + ((lastLoudness+PBS)/1.9)
        if (math.abs(PBS) > formula) == true then
            game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = (lastLoudness)
            if game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView <= 10 then
                print(formula, PBS) 
            else
                game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = 0
                print(formula, PBS)
            end
        end
    end
end
end --  <-- these bad boys don't go with anything
end --  <-- just remove them to get rid of the error
```

EDIT : Here's a more complete answer to help with your other script issues. You were resizing your animation stuff to 0 pixels tall, so you couldn't see anything.

```
-- to be placed in StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts

local Players = game:GetService("Players")

-- wait for local player PlayerGui
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer
local playerGui = LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")

-- create a ScreenGui
local screenGui = Instance.new("ScreenGui", playerGui)

-- create a holder for our bar
local frame = Instance.new("Frame", screenGui)
frame.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.0, 0.0)
frame.Position = UDim2.new(0.0, 0, 0.0, 0)
frame.Size = UDim2.new(1.0, 0, 0.0, 50) -- <-- this is no longer invisible

-- create a bar
local bar = Instance.new("Frame", frame)
bar.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
bar.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
bar.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0, 1, 0)

-- create a sound
local sound = Instance.new("Sound", screenGui)
local lastLoudness = 0
sound.SoundId = "rbxassetid://697821987"
sound.Looped = true
sound:Play()

-- define a max loudness
local maxLoudness = 30.0 -- <-- this needed to be a decimal value
local lastLoudness = 0

-- animate the amplitude bar
while true do
    -- PlaybackLoudness values range from 0 to 500, so downscale it
    local sampledLoundness = (sound.PlaybackLoudness / 50)
    local amplitude = math.clamp(sampledLoundness / maxLoudness, 0, 1)
    print("sound values : ", sound.PlaybackLoudness, maxLoudness, amplitude)

    -- animate the bar
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(amplitude, 0, 1, 0) -- <-- this was squashed to 0 pixels
    wait(0.00001)

    -- create a camera shake effect
    -- NOTE - not sure what the expected behavior is here, it just zooms in
    local PBS = sampledLoundness ^ sampledLoundness
    if lastLoudness ~=0 then
        local formula = math.abs(lastLoudness * 15) + ((lastLoudness + PBS) / 1.9)
        if (math.abs(PBS) > formula) == true then
            game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = lastLoudness
            if game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView <= 10 then
                print("FOV is less than 10 : ", formula, PBS) 
            else
                game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.FieldOfView = 0
                print("FOV forced to 0 : ", formula, PBS)
            end
        end
    end

    -- update lastLoudness and loop
    lastLoudness = sampledLoundness
end
```

Comment: that does nothing... :\

Comment: this is what the log said

Comment: 11:51:16.530 - Unfinished Disco.rbxl was auto-saved
  10 (x450)
11:51:34.563 - Disconnect from 127.0.0.1|61047

Comment: @Realsans22123, this is an entirely different message. The fact that it has auto saved that many times usually means that you left Studio open for a long time. And disconnecting from 127.0.0.1 means that there was a local server running and Studio closed the connection. Both of these messages point to the fact that you left Studio running for a long time.

Comment: i ran it for a couple of seconds actually

Comment: @Realsans22123, I'm sorry, I misread your last message. Comments don't add newlines. I tested out your script and I can see that the errors are gone, and that the 10 (x450) comes from your print(80-...) line. I think some of your confusion comes from having print statements that aren't helping you as much as they could. I'm going to edit my answer to add some better print statements to help you see what these numbers are. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you are resizing the bar.Size, but the Frames inside your ScreenGUI are Size(0,0,0,0) so you'll never see them. I'll add that in the answer.